# How to keep assembly plugin from failing on empty assemblies?

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a large, multi-module project. Many of the modules in this project need to create a secondary artifact for use in constructing the project distribution. I have created a shared assembly descriptor, which is working fine.

My current problem is that certain modules do not have any content that is picked up by the descriptor, which then causes the assembly plugin to fail because the assembly is empty.

Is there any way to keep the assembly plugin from falling over when an assembly is empty? I looked at the parameters for the single goal & couldn't find anything. I don't want to have to manually enable/disable this assembly on my individual modules, I want to configure the assembly on the parent and the child modules that don't have any content to skip creation on the assembly instead of failing.

Answer (score 0):

You could move your assembly plugin configuration into a `<pluginManagement>` section in the parent, then only specify the assembly plugin in the child modules that require it.

Parent:

```
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</plugin>
        <version>${your.version}</version>
        <configuration>
           <!-- whatever you have here now -->
        </configuration>
        <executions>
           <!-- whatever you have here now -->
        </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

Child that needs to create assembly:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <!-- Pull in config from the parent -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</plugin>
    </plugin>
  .....
  </plugins>
  .....
</build>
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I mentioned that's exactly what I **do not** want to do (i.e. manually enable). I want to define the execution on the parent & have the assembly plugin no-op instead of fail is there is nothing to assemble on the children.